# How do I verify an asc key fingerprint?

Tags: gnupg

At the moment, I'm trying to check the fingerprint of the oracle_vbox.asc key that I downloaded from http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads: they provide the key and the fingerprint but no instructions for reviewing this information myself.

How do I show the fingerprint of the key I just downloaded?

`apt-key finger oracle_vbox.asc` shows the fingerprints of all trusted keys, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Get the key:

```
$ wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc
```

Print the key fingerprint with GPG version 1:

```
$ gpg --with-fingerprint oracle_vbox.asc 
pub  1024D/98AB5139 2010-05-18 Oracle Corporation
                      (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
      Key fingerprint = 7B0F AB3A 13B9 0743 5925  D9C9 5442 2A4B 98AB 5139
sub  2048g/281DDC4B 2010-05-18
      Key fingerprint = 27B0 97CF 8257 4209 C434  8D42 B674 8A65 281D DC4B
```

Note that the 2nd fingeprint is just the fingerprint of the sub-key.

Print the fingerprint with GPG version 2:

```
$ gpg2 -n -q --import --import-options import-show  oracle_vbox.asc   
pub   dsa1024 2010-05-18 [SC]
      7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
uid   Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   elg2048 2010-05-18 [E]
```

Note that `-n` is an alias for `--dry-run`, i.e. the key isn't actually imported.

Alternatively, to just display the fingerprints:

```
$ gpg2 -nq --import --import-options import-show --with-colons oracle_vbox.asc \
     | awk -F: '$1 == "fpr" { print $10 }'
7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
27B097CF82574209C4348D42B6748A65281DDC4B
```

Comment: Is there an analogous command without using `gpg`? I mean, in SSH, I can do `cat ./id_rsa.pub | awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | md5sum` and it will return me an MD5 hash which is equal to the fingerprint hash of `ssh -lf ./id_rsa.pub`. Is there a similar way to do it with GPG public keys?

Comment: @user3019105, no, there is not. The format of a PGP public key is a little bit more complicated. See RFC 4880 and the GPG source code for details.

Comment: The RFC says (about MD5 deprecated fingerprints): `The fingerprint of a V3 key is formed by hashing the body (but not
   the two-octet length) of the MPIs that form the key material (public
   modulus n, followed by exponent e) with MD5.`, can't I get this MPIs' body given an ASCII Armor (Radix-64) public key file?

Comment: @user3019105, you can. You can duplicate what is already implemented in GPG. But such a command line would be quite more elaborate than the one you've posted for an ssh public key. Thus, it wouldn't be analogous.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I still need to find out how to get the `body of the MPIs that form the key material` the RFC talks about

Comment: Some explanatory **comments and references** could go a long way towards improving this answer (e.g. [Exchanging keys - GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x56.html)).

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty, well, I think that it's pretty spot on as-is. The question is just about displaying the fingerprint of a key file, thus the answer is just about that, as well. Adding more would arguably add more noise to the signal, so to say.

Comment: This syntax does not work with GnuPG 2 anymore. It outputs: `WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...`. Then, it lists the key without fingerprint. See my answer.

Comment: @ominug see my latest update for displaying the fingerprint with GPGv2 - without actually importing the key into a keyring.

Answer (score 9):

#### Step 1

`$ deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian artful contrib`

#### Step 2

`$ wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`

#### Step 3

```
$ apt-key list
```

or, equivalently,

```
$ apt-key finger
```

which should return

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [SC]
      B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
uid           [ unknown] Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [E]
```

which in turn should be equivalent to

> The key fingerprint for oracle_vbox_2016.asc is
>
> ```
> B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
> Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
> ```

on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads, either by visual inspection or further command line fu.

---

Related links:

- [Exchanging keys - GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x56.html)
- https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en

Comment: this question is missing some explanation...

Answer (score 2):

Using *gpg* version `2.2.27`

```
gpg --version

# output
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.4
```

Download the current `.asc` file from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads as of this writing (2023-03-22):

```
wget https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

The VirtualBox website currently states:

> The key fingerprint for oracle_vbox_2016.asc is
>
> ```
> B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
> Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
> ```

The following commands all allow to verify this information, each with different formatting:

```
gpg --show-keys --with-fingerprint --keyid-format=short oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output:

```
pub   rsa4096/2980AECF 2016-04-22 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
uid                    Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096/920E471F 2016-04-22 [E]
```

---

```
gpg --show-keys --with-fingerprint oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output:

```
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [SC]
      B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
uid                      Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [E]
```

---

```
gpg --show-keys oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output:

```
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [SC]
      B9F8D658297AF3EFC18D5CDFA2F683C52980AECF
uid                      Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   rsa4096 2016-04-22 [E]
```

---

```
gpg --show-keys --with-colons oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

Output ("*The `--with-colons` option emits the output in a stable, machine-parseable format, which is intended for use by scripts and other programs.*"):

```
pub:-:4096:1:A2F683C52980AECF:1461318881:::-:::scESC::::::23::0:
fpr:::::::::B9F8D658297AF3EFC18D5CDFA2F683C52980AECF:
uid:-::::1461318881::CA5D570DDFDB695A0301885765DD8E285368742C::Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>::::::::::0:
sub:-:4096:1:AD18C79D920E471F:1461318881::::::e::::::23:
fpr:::::::::31DD01EB8C64DF3D12E7BC97AD18C79D920E471F:
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with GPG 2 (at least I could check it with versions `2.1.18` and `2.2.12`):

```bsh
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc
gpg_home=$(mktemp -d)
gpg --homedir "$gpg_home" --import oracle_vbox.asc
# gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp.CHoWuJBy7N/pubring.kbx' created
# gpg: /tmp/tmp.CHoWuJBy7N/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
# gpg: key 54422A4B98AB5139: public key "Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>" imported
# gpg: Total number processed: 1
# gpg:               imported: 1
gpg --homedir "$gpg_home" --list-keys
# /tmp/tmp.CHoWuJBy7N/pubring.kbx
# -------------------------------
# pub   dsa1024 2010-05-18 [SC]
#       7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
# uid           [ unknown] Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
# sub   elg2048 2010-05-18 [E]
#
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468889

Answer (score 0):

You have both the key and the fingerprint? Run:

```
ssh-keygen -lf key.pub
```

against the key to get the fingerprint.

`ssh-keygen` reference: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ssh-keygen/

Comment: ssh-keygen doesn't recognize "oracle_vbox.asc" as a public key file.

Comment: my mistake, the command should be "ssh-keygen -lf"
Do you still get a nerror?

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: ssh-keygen -lf oracle_vbox_2016.asc                                                                                  
oracle_vbox_2016.asc is not a public key file.

Comment: ssh-keygen is not for PGP keys.