# How can I remove gpg key that I added using apt-key add -?

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg

I don't need the key in my server's keyring anymore. Is it possible to remove it? I added the key using this command:

```
 curl http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/GPG-key.txt | apt-key add -
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 265, accepted):

First you need to find the key id of the key you added. Do this by the command:

```
sudo apt-key list
```

It will list all the keys that you have, with each entry looking like this:

```
pub   1024R/B455BEF0 2010-07-29
uid                  Launchpad clicompanion-nightlies
```

Once you have figured out which key to remove, use the command `sudo apt-key del <keyid>` where `<keyid>` is replaced with the actual keyid of the key you want to remove from your keyring.

```
$ sudo apt-key del B455BEF0
$ apt-key list | grep clicompan
$
```

Comment: @Raymond No problemo :)

Comment: Ah I see the unique Id is on the line labelled pub, not the line labelled uid.

Comment: on ubuntu 16.10 results seems a little different :
`pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 ....
uid        ....`

Comment: Looks like this needs to be updated for 18.04

Comment: After deleting the key, I encountered a new problem `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY`, what should I do next ?

Comment: I found the answer, adding a `#` before the repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then re-run `sudo apt update`, works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: On 16.10 the short key id is no longer shown when you use the list command, but it is actually the last 8 characters of the long hex. from @wesam answer.

Comment: As the key id is no more shown just use the long hex string under pub and put in in quotes.

Answer (score 285):

On 16.10 the short key id is no longer shown when you use the list command, but it is actually the last 8 characters of the long hex.

So for example the key id for the following key

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>
```

The key id will be EFE21092

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. This is extremely unhelpful UX.

Comment: @SColvin you can just do `sudo apt-key del "8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092"` and I think it is safer to use the whole fingerprint, the keyid could have duplicates (at least when you use PGP for emails, I read you should share your whole fingerprint and not just the keyid).

Comment: has to be one of the stupidest `--help` listing (totally unclear what the id is)

Answer (score 45):

Update for Ubuntu 20.04

after running

```
sudo apt-key list
```

you should get the list of apt keys:

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2019-07-22 [S] [expires: 2022-07-21]

pub   rsa4096 2017-04-11 [SC] [expired: 2019-09-28]
      D4CC 8597 4C31 396B 18B3  6837 D615 560B A5C7 FF72
uid           [ expired] Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2017 <packager@opera.com>

pub   rsa4096 2019-09-12 [SC] [expires: 2021-09-11]
      68E9 B2B0 3661 EE3C 44F7  0750 4B8E C3BA ABDC 4346
uid           [ unknown] Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2019 <packager@opera.com>
sub   rsa4096 2019-09-12 [E] [expires: 2021-09-11]

pub   rsa4096 2017-03-13 [SC]
      8CAE 012E BFAC 38B1 7A93  7CD8 C5E2 2450 0C12 89C0
uid           [ unknown] TeamViewer GmbH (TeamViewer Linux 2017) <support@teamviewer.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-03-13 [E]
```

under `uid` you have the name of the app, for example:

```
[ unknown] Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2019 <packager@opera.com>
```

and the key you want to delete is above it:

```
    D4CC 8597 4C31 396B 18B3  6837 D615 560B A5C7 FF72  <-- THAT'S THE KEY
uid           [ expired] Opera Software Archive Automatic Signing Key 2017 <packager@opera.com>
```

and you remove it by putting that key inside double or single quotes like this:

```
sudo apt-key del "D4CC 8597 4C31 396B 18B3  6837 D615 560B A5C7 FF72"
```

Comment: it also worked for me to take the last 8 characters in the key and remove the space in between: sudo apt-key del A5C7FF72

Comment: yes... I think it would even work if you take any part of that key because it searches the pattern inside that whole key without spaces

Answer (score 5):

I made a short script to make things easier and using a string instead of the id.

You can use my script if the key contains a unique string you know. 
e.g. in my case for webmin

```
pub   1024D/11F63C51 2002-02-28
uid                  Jamie Cameron <jcameron@webmin.com>
sub   1024g/1B24BE83 2002-02-28
```

I'm sure only the webmin key on my system has `jcameron` than I use this script to remove the according key.

I saved it as `~/removeAptKey`

and run it as

```
sudo ./removeAptKey jcameron
```

The ouput should be something like

```
KEYID: 11F63C51
OK
```

Here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function printKeys(){
    echo "Installed keys are"
    echo ""
    sudo apt-key list
}

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "No key name provided"
    exit 1
fi

UNIQUE=$1

sudo apt-key list | grep "${UNIQUE}" -B 1 > result.temp

LENGTH=$(cat result.temp | wc -l)

if [[ ${LENGTH} -gt 2 ]]
then
    echo "Attention you found more than 1 key. Use a more specific string."
    printKeys
    exit 2
fi

if [[ ${LENGTH} != 2 ]]
then
    echo "Key not found. Doing nothing."
    printKeys
    exit 3
fi

KEYID=$(cat result.temp | grep 'pub' | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d "/" -f 2)
echo "KEYID: "$KEYID

apt-key del ${KEYID}

rm result.temp
```

First I get the upper two lines of my key's block:

- `sudo apt-key list`: lists the apt keys as usual
- `grep '${UNIQUE}' -B 1`: take only the line containing the unique key string `jcameron` and `-B 1` the line before
- `> result.temp`: Save it in a file (which is later removed)

If this returns exactly 2 lines (-> got exactly 1 key) I move on:

- `grep 'pub'`: Now take only the line with the `pup` key id
- `cut -d " " -f 4`: take the 4th word of that line (the first is `pub` than come two spaces, than the string we are after ``)
- `cut -d "/" -f 2`: take only the part after `/`

And finally delete this key and cleanup

- `apt-key del ${KEYID}` (in my case `11F63C51`)
- `rm result.temp`: don't need this file anymore

Comment: I ran this without a parameter and it just wiped out all my keys. ;(

Comment: If anyone else has their keys wipped, I was able to fix it by following these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/145933/13693

Comment: Hu? How did this happen? It should exit with an "No key name provided" if there was no parameter..

Comment: @derHugo not sure but could it be that the `#` in that if clause is the culprit?

Comment: @defuzed if you mean `$#` then no. It returns the amount of given parameters.

Answer (score 4):

I know I might be late, but just wanted to share this one-line command to achieve this.

**NOTE**: This will only work if the output is an unique key.

---

**Ubuntu versions up to 16.04 (UPDATED 2018-12-22):**

```
apt-key del $(apt-key list | awk 'NR=='$(apt-key list | grep --line-number --regexp "FOOBAR" | cut --fields 1 --delimiter ":")'{print;exit}' | awk '{print $2}' | cut --fields 2 --delimiter "/")
```

where `FOOBAR` is the UID name.

---

**Ubuntu versions from 16.10:**

```
apt-key del $(apt-key list | awk 'NR=='`expr $(apt-key list | grep --line-number --regexp "FOOBAR" | cut --fields 1 --delimiter ":") - 1`'{print;exit}')
```

where `FOOBAR` is the UID name.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I got an error when I tried to run the `16.04` command you provided. `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {` But the angle braces match, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work

Comment: @GabrielFair Thanks for noticing, back in june it has been working (I copy-pasted it from my console) but now seems that has been updated and the `apt-key list` format has changed. Now it seems to be working again. (EDIT: Remember to run this as superuser)

Answer (score 4):

I did this,

```
sudo apt-key list
```

Find the 'expired' key, then delete it, in my case,

```
sudo apt-key del "31CF B0B6 5659 B5D4 0DEE  C98D DFA1 75A7 5104 960E"
```

Then do

```
sudo apt update
```

The deleted key will say its not available note that string, in my case **DFA175A75104960E**

Then update the key like this, for my case DFA175A75104960E needed update,

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DFA175A75104960E
```

Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have the `.asc` key file, you can be sure you are deleting the right key with a command like this. (Replace `mykey.asc` with your key file below.)

```bsh
apt-key del "$(gpg -n -q --import --import-options import-show mykey.asc | grep '^pub' -A 1 | tail -n 1 | xargs)"
```

This command seems to work on Ubuntu 20.04. Credit for the `gpg` command goes to [maxschlepzig](https://askubuntu.com/users/1627/maxschlepzig) for their answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/151008/).

Comment: when i delete a key like so terminal tells me "OK" but later the error message is still the same. do i need a reboot?

Comment: @SL5net I don't think you should need to reboot after running this command, but you will probably need to run `apt update`. It's been a little while since I wrote this answer, though. What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something... but you can use the GUI also, on Settings of Software Updater:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes indeed... that's even easier