# How to remove a apt-key which I have added?

Tags: apt, repository

I added a key like this:

```
wget -q -O - https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
```

Now I want to remove this key. How can I do that? I don't know where it got added and how does it look like.

When I do `sudo apt-key list` it prints out few things on the console. Not sure which one is related to what I did above?

```
david@machine:~$ sudo apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <master@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <image@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <master@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <image@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024D/D50582E6 2009-02-01
uid                  Kohsuke Kawaguchi <kkiu@kyterty.org>
uid                  Kohsuke Kawaguchi <kyterty.iuytre@sun.com>
uid                  [jpeg image of size 3704]
sub   2048g/10AF40FE 2009-02-01

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//pubring.gpg
-----------------------------------
pub   2048R/06634014 2013-01-26
uid                  OSP Team <IET-OSP-IUY@host.com>
sub   2048R/732F28E7 2013-01-26
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/846877/224340 has one more solution without short key id.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`apt-key add` adds a key to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` by default.

These keys are from Ubuntu repositories:

```
pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <master@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <image@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <master@ubuntu.com>

pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <image@ubuntu.com>
```

Then you're left only with:

```
pub   1024D/D50582E6 2009-02-01
uid                  Kohsuke Kawaguchi <kkiu@kyterty.org>
uid                  Kohsuke Kawaguchi <kyterty.iuytre@sun.com>
uid                  [jpeg image of size 3704]
sub   2048g/10AF40FE 2009-02-01
```

Remove it by running:

```
sudo apt-key del D50582E6
```

---

If you really want to make sure you're removing the right key, you could add the key again to a new keyring:

```
wget -q -O - https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key --keyring /tmp/test add -
```

Then list its contents:

```
sudo apt-key --keyring /tmp/test list
```

Then you'll see the key you want to remove.

Comment: if you are wondering what is key, use last 8 letters together from the last two blocks out of ten blocks, like `D38B4796` from `EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796`

Comment: and if you prefer to copy and paste spaces are allowed inside quotes `sudo apt-key del 'D38B 4796'`

Comment: `sudo apt-key del "EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796"` would also work.

Comment: On Ubuntu 23 you'll get this error: `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`

Answer (score 11):

You can also directly remove key using

```
$ sudo apt-key list | grep 'teejee'
```

You will get

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/teejee2008-ppa.gpg
```

Then,

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/teejee2008-ppa.gpg
```

Just Test again with `$ sudo apt-key list | grep 'teejee'`

Comment: askubuntu.com is not like a traditional forum, it is a community curated question and answer site. New good answers are encouraged, even on old questions. Answers are better when they explain the commands used in them. And show both a general form and the form suitable for the question. It is also courteous to include references/acknowledgement  of any sources. Such as the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604988/how-to-remove-a-apt-key-which-i-have-added/988250#comment845442_604993) on one of the other answers. [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/788129)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @RussBateman now please give me up-vote. Thank You.

Comment: I'm not the one that down-voted your answer, but I've up-voted with the edit certainly.

Comment: Sorry mate. I was unaware of that.

Comment: I get `Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)`

Answer (score 10):

Open the software center, go to "Edit" → "Software Sources ..." → "Other Software" and you see a "Remove" button.

Comment: Well, I have Ubuntu machine which only has command line stuff. No UI stuff at all.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:the/ppa`

Comment: hmm, what  will be my `ppa`. I don't know much about these stuff. Is it there in the two command which I executed?