# How do I uninstall wine on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wine, 17.04

Every time I try to uninstall wine I get this:

[image: Command line screenshot]

I used winehq to install it. 
https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: Instead of uploading image, Please consider copy pasting the text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the wiki page you linked, the name of the package is not `wine`, choose one of the three package names that are listed and your command will likely work better:

- winehq-stable
- winehq-devel
- winehq-staging

Or just try: `sudo apt-get purge winehq*`

You can then also run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean up.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've spent all day trying to  figure this out.  I can't believe I didn't try that.

Comment: No problem :) please mark this as an answer if it solved your issue. Cheers

Comment: I also found it necessary to update my sources list `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` and I removed the gpg key following these steps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/604988/how-to-remove-a-apt-key-which-i-have-added