# GPG error : http://repos.rcn-ee.net

Tags: apt, updates, repository

when I update using `apt-get update` on Beaglebone black, I got the following error,

```
W: GPG error: http://repos.rcn-ee.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D284E608A4C46402
```

I've tried following command given in some forum

```
$ apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key D284E608A4C46402
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.YlaPkjE1g4 --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key D284E608A4C46402
gpg: requesting key A4C46402 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key D284E608A4C46402 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

and I've tried

```
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key D284E608A4C46402'
gpg: requesting key A4C46402 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key D284E608A4C46402 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

$ gpg -a --export D284E608A4C46402 | sudo apt-key add -
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

I'm behind proxy, and configured /etc/apt/apt.conf and /etc/environment files and aswell exported the proxy setting in terminal, pinging any site from terminal is working.

and still I get the GPG error same as above, can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: If you added these repositories yourself, better check the instructions again. I don't think the owners of these repos have published their keys (so checking a keyserver might not be useful), and worse, I think the owners of repos.rcn-ee.net have no sense of security at all (their repository signing key is out there visible for the entire world to see).

Comment: Actually I've installed an image of ubuntu14.04 version provided by Robert C Nelson (rcn.ee.net) on Beaglebone black

Comment: for your other question also do the same thing muru has already stated above.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/611221/gpg-error-http-packages-osrfoundation-org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install rcn-ee-archive-keyring
```

solution courtesy: RobertCNelson

Comment: Not working. What repository should this package come from?

Answer (score 3):

save the whole content of [this](http://repos.rcn-ee.net/ubuntu/conf/repos.rcn-ee.net.gpg.key) link in `~/key` . Then in terminal, type

`sudo apt-key add ~/key`

and you should get an `OK` message.

---

Further reading: [How to remove keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107177/how-can-i-remove-gpg-key-that-i-added-using-apt-key-add)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you might have a link to an out-of-date keyring, so you might need to look at http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/pool/main/r/rcn-ee-archive-keyring/ to see what the latest version is. For example, I needed to do:

```
wget http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/pool/main/r/rcn-ee-archive-keyring/rcn-ee-archive-keyring_2015.10.22~bpo70+20151022+1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i rcn-ee-archive-keyring_2015.10.22~bpo70+20151022+1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest upgrades (eg from buster to bullseye) you should use http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/pool/main/b/bbb.io-keyring/ as the keyring to update.
So:

```
wget http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/pool/main/b/bbb.io-keyring/bbb.io-keyring_1.20220421.0-0~bullseye+20220421_all.deb
dpkg -i bbb.io-keyring_1.20220421.0-0~bullseye+20220421_all.deb
```