# GPG error: http://packages.osrfoundation.org

Tags: apt, updates

when I update using '`apt-get update`' on ubuntu-14.04, I got the following error,

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.osrfoundation.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 67170598AF249743
```

I've tried following command given in some forum

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 67170598AF249743
```

the output is as follows

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.XI2D9gTkMc --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://202.141.80.80:3128 --recv-key 67170598AF249743
gpg: requesting key AF249743 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 67170598AF249743 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

and I've tried

```
 gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 67170598AF249743
```

the output is

```
gpg: requesting key AF249743 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 67170598AF249743 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

with command `gpg -a --export 67170598AF249743 | sudo apt-key add -`, I got the following result

```
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

and still I get the GPG error same as above, can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Are you running these commands under sudo privilege ? ie sudo  gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 67170598AF249743 ?

Comment: yeah i've logged in as root into terminal

Comment: by the way do you really need OSRF   Repository ? I mean packages.osrfoundation.org ? As a work around you can exclude it and run update.. here is how .. http://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository

Comment: I've added the repos of gazebo myself, will the GPG keys be available in keyserver.ubuntu.com for those repos added by user?

Comment: you should have mentioned this at the start of your question, just like your other question... http://askubuntu.com/questions/611209/gpg-error-http-repos-rcn-ee-net

Comment: the other question was solved with
apt-get install rcn-ee-archive-keyring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems keyserver.ubuntu.com is missing gpg keys for packages.osrfoundation.org

Download gazebo.key from below using wget..

```
wget  http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key
```

and import it

```
sudo apt-key add gazebo.key
```

Then try

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: check latest edit