# Ubuntu 16.04 Error: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: ssh, putty

I run `apt-get update` and I see this error:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
```

How to remove that error? Log:

```
Hit:1 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirror.timeweb.ru/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x trusty InRelease
Err:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x trusty InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_4.x/dists/trusty/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Before I only deleted key by this [How can I remove gpg key that I added using apt-key add -?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107177/how-can-i-remove-gpg-key-that-i-added-using-apt-key-add/107189)

Edit: I'm only trying to isntall websocket with nodejs from this manual https://by-example.org/install-node-js-4-3-lts-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-lts/ , before this error show I run first 3 commands from that manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start **Software & Updates** from the dash, and go to the Authentication tab to delete incorrect keys.

You can try installing y-ppa-manager from Synaptic, and then start PPA Manager from the Dash. Click on the Advanced icon, and then choose **import all missing gpg keys**.

**Update #1:**

To add the PPA...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
sudo y-ppa-manager
```

Comment: Did PPA Manager solve your problem? Please rate my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. I did not find y-ppa-manager in synaptic.

Comment: @user87317 I've updated my answer to help you.

Comment: thanks. In my case the problem was an Opera key, which I fixed using these instructions: https://forums.opera.com/topic/22315/ubuntu-apt-get-is-telling-me-public-key-not-available/2

Answer (score 0):

2022 version =)

`curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg add -`

Initially I tried to install the key to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` as is instructed by apt-key (which is being deprecated btw.) but somehow that failed:

`curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nodesource.gpg add -`