# Ubuntu update to 22.04.1 LTS failed with empty error message

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

Upgrade to `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` failed with a e empty error message.

### what happened

As message popped up to upgrade to `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`

[image: Upgrade available to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS]

there i pressed the button `Upgrade` and got this message
( `Upgrade failed with the following output:` )

[image: Upgrade failed with the following output:]

#### System Info

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-56-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

#### apt-get update

Because for a user hensem this works i tried:
`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && do-release-upgrade` ( https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=164058&start=15 )

there i got errors

```sh
Err:3 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                         
The following signatures couldn't be verified 
because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yt-dlp/stable/ubuntu 
focal Release                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]
```

then i used about 3 times

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 
TheKeyFromCopyPast
```

with results:

```
gpg: key 23F3D4EA75716059: public key "GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && do-release-upgrade`

```sh
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yt-dlp/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                             
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yt-dlp/stable/ubuntu focal Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 80]

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/yt-dlp/stable/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

#### do-release-upgrade

found a command at https://community.keyhelp.de/viewtopic.php?p=38404

```sh
do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

So how i could
install all available updates for your release before upgrading
without errors?

Any idea?

Comment: Remove all software installed from non-Ubuntu sources and also remove the sources. One way to do that is with the `ppa-purge` command. You obviously have a problem with software sources - how have you been doing updates?

Comment: For Updates i usually look every two days in "Status and Notifications" Bar and press  "Updates". Then "Updates- Discover" pops up and i press update all. Yes as a developer i have many non-Ubuntu sources (maybe the most of my sources). First i do a backup now and then i try to remove maybe them.

Comment: i have installed  ppa-purge, should i do maybe 'ppa-purge -s http://ppa.launchpad.net/yt-dlp/stable/ubuntu' ?

Comment: i did "sudo apt-get autoremove gh;" and now the Update seems staring. I see the Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 'Jammy Jellyfish' message

Comment: `the public key is not available:`, I've seen this as a transient error. Unless it's urgent I'd wait a day and try again, maybe try using different mirrors.

Answer (score 3):

#### network was overloaded

My guess: The network was overloaded for this task on Saturday. The update was new and probably a lot of people tried to do it at the same time.

#### what i did

maybe there is no causal connection with what I did yesterday. Maybe yes. I did the following:

Freed up 50 GB more hard drive space. Were before maybe 10 GB free.

Try to remove GitHub CLI and the public key of it:

```sh
sudo apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2022-09-06 [SC] [expires: 2024-09-06]
      2C61 0620 1985 B60E 6C7A  C873 23F3 D4EA 7571 6059
uid           [ unknown] GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>
sub   rsa4096 2022-09-06 [E] [expires: 2024-09-06]

sudo apt-key del 23F3D4EA75716059
OK
```

read https://askubuntu.com/a/1407703/1017209 then:

```sh
sudo apt-key del "2C61 0620 1985 B60E 6C7A  C873 23F3 D4EA 7571 6059"
OK

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 23F3D4EA75716059
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.fW5y5VuWvv/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 23F3D4EA75716059
gpg: key 23F3D4EA75716059: public key "GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

But message still the same:

```sh
sudo apt update
Err:1 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                           
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
```

#### Next Day

maybe there is no causal connection:

have video chat(jitsi), wrote emails(webmail), played an open source game(0ad), took a walk, was sleeping(Sat to Son). I woke up and when I switched on the computer I immediately clicked on upgrade again (this time it went through without an error message, without interruption).

[image]

[image: i pressed replace config of ImageMagick]

[image: restart system]

the time taken was: 32 Minutes (11:39 - 11:07 at Sunday 11th Dec. 2022 )

Answer (score 1):

After reading the above and getting the same update error message with an empty message box, I looked at my library of data sources for packages and saw nothing unusual except for microsoft (for the microsoft-edge-stable package). I ran an "apt remove microsoft-edge-stable", restarted my machine and the update ran with no issues. It did remove some old/outdated/incompatible packages, but that is generally not an issue.

I did not remove the source, so (should I need to) I could reinstall the edge browser (not likely).

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar situation a couple months ago. The guidance from Organic Marble is totally valid, but for me, it created other problems taking that approach (perhaps due to my own sloppiness). If you need or prefer another route, what I did was use [Aptik](https://teejeetech.com/aptik-3/), a system migration tool, to do my backup, and then did a fresh install off of a thumbdrive.