# How to remove expired keys within the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg file?

Tags: apt, updates, repository

Thanks to the following valuable tutorial

- [Fixing "Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring" Issue in Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/key-is-stored-in-legacy-trusted-gpg/)

Specifically through the `Method 1: Import the key [Proper but complicated way]` section was resolved the following message:

```
Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details
```

The following commands are important

```
sudo apt-key list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   dsa1024 2003-02-03 [SCA] [expired: 2022-02-16]
      A4A9 4068 76FC BD3C 4567  70C8 8C71 8D3B 5072 E1F5
uid           [ expired] MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>

pub   rsa4096 2021-12-14 [SC] [expired: 2023-12-14]
      859B E8D7 C586 F538 430B  19C2 467B 942D 3A79 BD29
uid           [ expired] MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>

pub   rsa4096 2023-10-23 [SC] [expires: 2025-10-22]
      BCA4 3417 C3B4 85DD 128E  C6D4 B7B3 B788 A8D3 785C
uid           [ unknown] MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
sub   rsa4096 2023-10-23 [E] [expires: 2025-10-22]
```

It to know what key must be fixed within the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` file, here appears two kinds, either *expired* or *expires*. Because the latest key is still valid was used

```
sudo apt-key export A8D3785C | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

Therefore when the `sudo apt update` is executed the mentioned message shown in the first block disappears

The reason of this post

- How to remove **expired** keys within the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` file?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107177/how-can-i-remove-gpg-key-that-i-added-using-apt-key-add has all you need (probably)

Comment: It worked. Thank You